# PL/SQL Function returning wrong result

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, sql-navigator

I've a PL/SQL function below that's returning a wrong result in SQL Navigator and SQL Developer, but is returning the right answer in SQL Plus.

We've a script running that's executing it and returning the wrong answer too, so trying to fix it. Can anyone see any issues with it? It works fine for most people, but I've a few people going into and returning null/nothing in SQL Navigator and Developer. It's not populating l_end_date for them, and thus credits not populating.

Works fine then in SQL Plus for some reason.

```
    create or replace function mis_get_mem_lcr_credits(p_mem_no in number) RETURN  number is
    --
       v_lcr_credit   number;
       l_mem_no       number;
       l_start_date   date;
       l_end_date     date;
       l_dob          date;
       l_18th_date    date;
    --
       cursor c1 is
       select mem_no, ind_birth_dt
       from cd_individual
       where mem_no = l_mem_no
       and pkg_mem_utils.get_member_age(mem_no,ind_birth_dt) >= 18
       and nvl(ind_student_flag,'N') = 'N'
       order by mem_no, ind_birth_dt;
    --
       cursor c2 is
       select distinct m_effdt,
              m_termdt
       from cd$v_member_contracts9 cd1,
            cd_member_product_link cd2
       where cd1.mem_no = l_mem_no
       and cd1.policy_no = cd2.policy_no
       and cd1.m_effdt = cd2.mem_product_eff_dt --.2
       and (l_18th_date between cd1.m_effdt and cd1.m_termdt OR cd1.m_effdt > l_18th_date)--.3 18 at time of contract effective date
       and nvl(cd1.lapsed_to_start,'N') = 'N'
       and cd2.product_id not in (14,41,31) -- Exclude No Cover, DentalProtect and HealthProtect
       and cd2.product_id NOT IN (select distinct product_id
                                  from cd_product_options
                                  where nvl(allowed_for_lcr,'Y') = 'N')
       order by cd1.m_effdt ASC;
    --
    begin
    --
       l_mem_no       := p_mem_no;
       v_lcr_credit   := 0;
       l_dob          := null;
    --
       for crec in c1 loop            
       --
          l_dob := crec.ind_birth_dt;
       --
        --  l_18th_date := substr(to_char(l_dob,'DD/MM/YYYY'),0,6)||(substr(to_char(l_dob,'DD/MM/YYYY'),7,4)+18);

           if to_char(l_dob) like '29-02%' then
                    l_18th_date :=    add_months(to_date(l_dob+1),216 );
            else
                    l_18th_date :=   add_months(to_date(l_dob), 216);
            end if;

       --       

          for crec2 in c2 loop
          --



             if crec2.m_termdt > sysdate then
             --
                l_end_date := sysdate;            
             --         
             else
             --
                l_end_date := crec2.m_termdt;
             --
             end if;
          --
             if v_lcr_credit = 0 then --earliest contract
             --
                if l_18th_date between crec2.m_effdt and crec2.m_termdt then
                --
                   v_lcr_credit := v_lcr_credit + months_between(l_end_date,l_18th_date);
                --
                else
                --
                   v_lcr_credit := v_lcr_credit + months_between(l_end_date,crec2.m_effdt);
                --
                end if;
             --
             else
             --
                v_lcr_credit := v_lcr_credit + months_between(l_end_date,crec2.m_effdt);
             --
             end if;
          --
          end loop;
       --
       end loop;
    --
       return round(nvl(v_lcr_credit,0));

    --
    end mis_get_mem_lcr_credits;
    /
    show errors

    spool off

    exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Never, ever use `to_date()` on a `DATE` value.

`to_date()` converts a **`varchar`** to a `date`.

If you call it with a `DATE` the date value gets converted to a varchar which then gets converted back to a date which it was to begin with - and being subject to the evil implicit data type conversion twice in that process.

The variable `l_dob` is defined as `DATE` so you have to change

```
add_months(to_date(l_dob+1),216 );
...
add_months(to_date(l_dob), 216);
```

to

```
add_months(l_dob+1,216);
...
add_months(l_dob, 216);
```

Comment: @Horse..one question out of curiosity,then why its returning the right answer in SQL Plus ???

Comment: @Raj_Te: because there the evil implicit data type conversion happens to work as you expect it (see Plirkee's answer).

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Didn't even consider that, thought the error was in the c2 cursor and spent hours looking at that to figure it out.

Comment: @horse..So it means implicit data type conversion only happens in SQL PLUS and doesnot happen in SQL Navigator and SQL Developer. right?

Comment: @Raj_Te: no - it happens in both. But in SQL*Plus it happens to work correctly and in the other tools it happens to convert it to some date that doesn't return the correct values.

Comment: @Horse..Thank you very much..!! Understood

Comment: What you get from converting a date to a string without specifying a format will depend on the environment settings at runtime, so for example `if to_char(l_dob) like '29-02%'` will never be true for someone whose `nls_date_format` is `DD-MON-YYYY`, `YYYY-MM-DD`, `MM/DD/YYYY` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Could be because of different values of

`NLS_TERRITORY`, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` etc. in different environments.
So I would suggest to set explicitly these values in your script. e.g. something like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=''AMERICA''';`

Some References:

[NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119)

[NLS_TERRITORY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/initparams132.htm)